# exclude roles from overview

Tags: user-roles, users

I am re-using some old code on a new website where I show all users in a listing with last post image as background. This all works fine (I know the get_users_of_blog is deprecated, but when I use get_users my code breaks)...

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
if ($blogusers) { 
  foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) { 
    $args = array( 
      'author' => $bloguser->user_id, 
      'showposts' => 1,
      'caller_get_posts' => 1
    ); 
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args); 

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>  
        ...........
      <?php endwhile; 
    } 
  } 
} 
?>
```

The thing is I can't get it ordered by name and exclude authors in the list. I tried doing this

```
$blogusers = get_users_of_blog(array('role' => 'editors', 'orderby => ID));
```

But this is not doing a darn thing. Anyone? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `get_users_of_blog()` function is deprecated, and the reason your code breaks after using [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) is the `->user_id` part, you should use `->ID` instead.

```
$blogusers = get_users();

if ($blogusers) { 

  foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) { 

    $args = array( 
      'author'           => $bloguser->ID, 
      'showposts'        => 1,
    ); 

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args); 

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>  
        ...........
      <?php endwhile; 
    } 

  } 

}
```

If you are on a multisite, you should set the `blog_id` argument of `get_users` to your blog's ID.

Now, about excluding the authors. If you take a look at the [author parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) of `WP_Query()`, there's a `author__not_in` argument that accepts an array of author IDs. So, to exclude the `test` role from your query, set the `role__in` or `role` argument of `get_users()` to `test`, and then use the results in your `WP_Query()`. You didn't provide accurate details so I'm not sure what exactly you are looking after, but these should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this to exclude authors from the get_users

$blogusers = get_users(array( 'role' => 'editor' ));

And works like a charm! Thanks again!